# Is it possible having multiple names or aliases for webmethods for web services in .NET Framework 4?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-4.0

Currently, I'm working on changing the name of some web methods in a web service.

```
[WebMethod(MessageName ="HelloWorld2",MessageName = "HelloWorld")]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

I wonder: is it possible to have different message names for the same method? Or something with the same result?

Answer (score 0):

My first approach is calling the new implementation from the old method. I'm open to ideas

```
[WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld2(string s)
    {
        return $"Hello {s}";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld3(string s)
    {
        return HelloWorld2(s);
    }
```